# Is it bad form to include <span> and <br> within <td> elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to programming and I was recently playing around with APIs and AJAX. The API that I'm using grabs me website descriptions for a specified URL. I want this description to appear *under* a link (to that URL) upon hovering. My problem is, the link appears in a table cell and I want the URL description to appear under the link, in the same cell. What I have right now works, however, it appends `<span>` and `<br>` to a `<td>`. Is this bad form? Should I try something else?

**HTML:**

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td class="heading">Blah</td>
       <td>BlahBlah</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td class="heading">Website</td>
       <td id="website"><a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
.urlWebsite {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
var $table = $('#website a');

$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url: "[insert API url here]",
    success: function(website){
        $table.hover(function(){
            $table.append('<br><span class="urlWebsite">'+website.description+'</span>');
        }, function(){
            $table.find("span").last().remove();
            $table.find("br").last().remove();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having additional tags inside of a table cell.

Comment: it's less worse than not using thead, tbody, tfoot and caption tags

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with that.  Table rows and columns are only meant to delineate content.  It doesn't matter what content that is.

You could even put a div inside the td and wrap that with an a tag and make the entire cell clickable.

Also, should be using `thead` and `tbody` inside of your table.